# ERP changes visibility status of products

Tags: magento2, product, visibility

We are facing a stupid problem. Our Magento 2 shop is connected to an external ERP system. Our ERP system sends back the status to the shop as it should, once the products are shipped and sets the order to "Complete" from "Processing".

Now, whenever this happens, our sample articles, which are set to "Not visible individually" change the status to "Catalog Search". Articles remain the same but visibility status gets changed constantly.

Does anyone of you out there understands the logic of this setting and can give a hint, how I can prevent this change?

Best regards

Comment: I think the issue is coming from your custom code. Please, check event, plugin, custom functions again.

Comment: Hi. Tried that. It seems, somehow the Cron is changing the status. Do you have any idea, where I can observe or try to monitor what is happening in the sytem?